# Node.js passport doesn't redirect on failureRedirect

Tags: node.js, passport.js

So I'm trying to make a node.js project with passport authentification. When I log in with correct credentials, login works perfectly. But if I try to log in with wrong password and correct email, instead of redirecting back to login page, the site just keeps on loading indefinetly.

Here is my server.js code:

```
  require('dotenv').config();
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const passport = require('passport');
    const initializePassport = require('./passport-config');
    const session = require('express-session');
    const methodOverride = require('method-override');
initializePassport(
    passport,
    async email=>{
        try{
            let bookshelfUser = await createBookshelfOf("User");
            return await new bookshelfUser().where("email", email).fetch().then((data)=>{
                return data.attributes;
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            return null;
        }},
    async id=>{
        try{
            let bookshelfUser = await createBookshelfOf("User");
            return await new bookshelfUser().where("id", id).fetch().then((data)=>{
                return data.attributes;
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            return null;
        }});
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect : '/',
        failureRedirect  : '/login',
    })
);
```

And this is passport-config

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
    console.log("Passport initialized");
    const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
        const user = await getUserByEmail(email);
        if (user == null) {
            console.log("No user with that email");
            return done(null, false, { message: 'No user with that email' });
        }

        try {
            await bcrypt.compare(password, user.geslo, (err, result)=>{
                if (err){
                    console.log("Password incorrect");
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' });
                }
                if(result){
                    console.log("User logged in successfully: " + user.username);
                    return done(null, user);
                }
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            return done(e)
        }
    }

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, authenticateUser));
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id));
    passport.deserializeUser(async(id, done) => {
        return done(null, await getUserById(id));
    })
}

module.exports = initialize
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible issues:

- you're mixing promises with callbacks for `bcrypt.compare()`, which may not work (but perhaps it might, I don't know `bcrypt` too well);
- it's not an error when a password doesn't match a hash for `bcrypt.compare()`; instead, `result` will be `false`, and you're not handling that case.

Here's a rewritten version of the block:

```
try {
  const result = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.geslo);
  if (! result) {
    console.log("Password incorrect");
    return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' });
  } else {
    console.log("User logged in successfully: " + user.username);
    return done(null, user);
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
  return done(e)
}
```

Comment: Ok apperantly this worked now, but previously it was somehow always returning false. Thank you